# NestJS exporting library to pdf or excel

Tags: nestjs

Is there any NestJS have library for exporting file like pdf or excel?

I'm trying to use nodeJS library. but it's not working. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different packages from npm to export data as pdf or csv.

Here is the [export-to-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/export-to-csv) package to export data as csv

```
yarn add export-to-csv
```

And here the [nestjs-pdf](https://github.com/toondaey/nestjs-pdf) package to export data as pdf

```
yarn add nestjs-pdf
```